# is there a way to create a custom action for a standard web api "publish" via visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently publishing my Web API app to different environments via the basic method of right-clicking on the Web API project and clicking "Publish" and then selecting a pre-defined publish profile.

I've created a "WebConfigs" folder with a Web.config for each environment.  For example, Web.test.config, Web.staging.config, Web.prod.config.  Before I publish to an environment, I need to overwrite the contents of the root-level Web.config file with the contents of the environment-specific Web.config.

Is there any type of hook I can create in a Publish profile to accomplish this automatically, as opposed to having to manually overwrite the contents of the root-level Web.config every time I publish?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for web.config transformation. [These microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) are probably what you want.

Comment: that's interesting but that seems to add a lot of potential complexity.  I would prefer to figure out a way to simply replace the contents of the Web.config file.

Comment: Hm, I personally don't know of a simpler way to accomplish it without doing it manually, but perhaps someone else will.

Comment: Right click publish isn't very good from a devops perspective. You have no way of ensuring that your code flows from environment to environment properly. No traceability. Have you considered using build and release management tooling? Such as [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/), [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/), [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), or [Octopus](https://octopus.com/)? They allow you to define custom tasks to do during your releases.